# Return the values from each method into an object array

Tags: php, class, oop

Learning php OOP...

I need the values of the two methods ($theme and $panel) to replace Foo and Bar.

I am trying to return a single object array that has $theme and $panel with one call the the Test class.

```
class Test {
        
    public $parent_theme_settings;
    public $admin_panel_settings;
    
    public function __construct() {     
        $this->parent_theme_settings = 'foo';       
        $this->admin_panel_settings = 'bar';
    }   
    
    public function parent_theme_settings() {       
        $theme = file_get_contents( plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/parent-theme-config.json' );     
        return $theme;      
    }

    public function admin_panel_settings() {
        $panel = get_option( 'settings_panel' );                
        return $panel;
    }

}
$FooBar = new Test();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Have you tried `$FooBar->functionname()`, i.e., `$FooBar->parent_theme_settings()`?

Comment: _"I need the values of the two methods to replace Foo and Bar"_ - for this you need setters. _"I am trying to return a single object array."_ - this I don't understand. Return what and where?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Yes and it returns the value for just that method. I want to call the Test class once and get the values from each method. An object array that contains $theme and $panel.

Comment: @El_Vanja $theme and $panel in an object array where ever I call the Test class.

Comment: Seems like you have much to learn about classes. What you're doing in your two methods you should be doing in the constructor (immediately initializing your properties to what they need to be). Once they're initialized, writing a method that returns those two values as an array becomes trivial.

Comment: @El_Vanja I know I am just starting and so far I have been picking it up, but I can find any examples to learn from.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

Either move the code from the methods to `__construct()` or call the methods there:

```
public function __construct() {     
    $this->parent_theme_settings = $this->parent_theme_settings();       
    $this->admin_panel_settings  = $this->admin_panel_settings();
}
```

I don't know what you mean by *return a single object array*, you can't `return` from the constructor.  You can have another method that returns an array:

```
public function get_settings() {
    return [$this->parent_theme_settings(),
            $this->admin_panel_settings()];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think foo and bar are values inside your properties, so to change these values you have to change the properties that hold these values either by setting setters or a special function that do the job for you.